# Keep pandas index while applying sklearn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which has a DateTime index and I'm using PCA from sklearn to reduce the number of dimensions.

The following question bugs me - will PCA keep the order of the points in my series so that I can reuse the index from the original dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df2 = pca.fit_transform(df)
df2.index = df.index
```

Moreover, is there a better (safer) approach than doing this?

Comment: Maybe reindexing would help -  `pca.fit_transform(df).reindex(index=df.index)`?

Comment: And is there any difference in what I am doing?

Comment: Not likely though. This would get rid of the unnecessary re-assignment of index axis.

Answer (score 2):

Though the indices are removed by PCA but the underlying order of rows remains(see implementation for the transform function of PCA*). So it is safe to have df2.index = df1.index

*fit_transform is same as fit and then transform. None of them reorder the rows.

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover, is there a better (safer) approach than doing this?

What you do is safe. But a *cleaner* way to do this is to wrap the output in either a `DataFrame` or `Series` and provide the original index. In your example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pca.fit_transform(df), index=df.index)
```

This is very useful when dealing with prediction vectors (np.ndarrays) out of a sci-kit learn model:

```py
y_pred = pd.Series(clf.predict(X_train), index=X_train.index)
```

This is important when you have a more complicated index, like a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html).